# Arrays within Arrays in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to display, in an Angular page, a sample list of data stored in a file.  This is for a data dictionary application.   It means I don't know ahead of time the field names since it could be any file and any number of columns.  My JSON looks like this ( although I'm flexible if it needs adjusting ).

```
 [{
    "FileName": "QUOTHDR",
    "Records": [{
            "Row": [
                " 7", " 1", " ", " 15", " 71", " ", " 6617", " 1", " 1", " ", " ", " R-2017-0063674", " 2017-06-15-08.58.44.817197", " .0000", " ", " 60007", " ORIGIN (1)", " ", " ", " 174", " ", " 141741", " 1", " ", "2017-06-15-09.23.14.831709", " 6617", " ", " ", " 2017-06-15-09.34.09.200973"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Row": [
                " 7", " 1", " ", " 15", " 71", " ", " 6617", " 1", " 1", " ", " ", " R-2017-0063674", " 2017-06-15-08.58.44.817197", " .0000", " ", " 60007", " ORIGIN (1)", " ", " ", " 174", " ", " 141741", " 1", " ", "2017-06-15-09.23.14.831709", " 6617", " ", " ", " 2017-06-15-09.34.09.200973"
            ]
        }
    ]
 }]
```

I implement this in my service:

```
    export interface ITableSampleData2 {
    fileName: string;
    Records: any[] ;
    }

And my HTML iterates the Records array and the Row Array like:
            <tbody>
                <div *ngFor="let tsd of tableSampleData">

                <tr *ngFor="let row of tsd.Row;">                        

                    <td  *ngFor="let dta of row;  let i = index">
                        {{dta[i]}}
                    </td>

                </tr>
                </div>
            </tbody>
```

I have searched for a number of examples, used ng-repeat, *ngFor with [].  Nothing seems to work.   I think I'm close but I'm either getting nothing coming out or errors in the console log.  I've also tried {{i}}.  Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `tableSampleData` a collection of ITableSampleData2 ? you have to iterate (ngFor) over the Records array, then on Row ... ```<div *ngFor="let tsd of tableSampleData.Records">
                <tr *ngFor="let row of tsd.Row;">                        
                    <td  *ngFor="let dta of row">
                        {{dta}}
                    </td>
                </tr></div>``` should work

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The problem is, it does not display anything.  This is the issue I've been having all along.  Code that looks like it should work it not working.   Nothing is displayed with {{dta}}

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting lost in the iterations.

It should look like this if you do it the "right way":

```
/* I removed the <div> inside the <tbody>, just to clarify :) */
<tbody *ngFor="let tsd of tableSampleData">
    /* ... */
    <tr *ngFor="let record of tsd.Records;">
        <td  *ngFor="let dta of record.Row;  let i = index">
            /* ... */
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.   I modified your code above to indicate what loop is printing:

<tbody *ngFor="let tsd of tableSampleData">
    /* .aa.. */
    <tr *ngFor="let record of tsd.Records">
        /* .bb.. */
        <td  *ngFor="let dta of record.Row">
            /* .cc.. */
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

The interesting thing is only the /* .aa.. */ are printing.  That tells me that it is not getting into the second loop for some reason.